# How to add app in current project using Firebase Cli

Tags: android, firebase, command-line-interface

Hi i am writing a script which created apk dynamically from scripts as i have package name manually on firebase Console for the apk which are created from my system.Can any body suggest how to add app dynamically in my project using CLI

Comment: share the code that you have done, and the tutorials that you followed

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no CLIs or tools for adding an app programmatically to a Firebase project.  However, there is new REST API for creating and modifying projects and apps within it.  You will need to learn the [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/), which is in beta.  To create a new Android app in the project, you will need to call the [androidApps endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/#rest-resource-v1beta1projectsandroidapps).